# Applying PresentationFramework.Royale style to .net 4.8 wpf project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, dll

I have a WPF application where I have two stylesheets xaml. But I need to apply base style i.e PresentationFramework.Royale to only one of them, which is not directly loaded in App.xaml.

Below is my App.xaml. I do not want to refer PresentationFramework.Royale here,

```html
<Application
    x:Class="UI.Desktop.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UI.Common;component/Style.Shui.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have a login view usercontrol to which i need to add PresentationFramework.Royale as base style along with another stylesheet. How can I achieve this,

```html
<UserControl
    x:Class="Views.Implementation.Common.LoginView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Royale, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/royale.normalcolor.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Test.APP.UI.Common;component/Style.Test1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Button
            x:Name="Login"
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Width="85"
            Margin="0,0,15,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="Login"
            IsDefault="True"
            TabIndex="8"
            ToolTip="Login" />        
</UserControl>
```

The issue is above code Style.Test1.xaml controls does not take royale.normalcolor.xaml as base. But it works if I put royale.normalcolor.xaml reference in App.xaml

Comment: Merge `PresentationFramework.Royale` into `Style.Test1.xaml`.

Comment: Have tried that too, And it did not work.